# c# encryption algorithms application

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I need a c# application use encryption algorithms to encrypt/decrypt strings
such as DES,SDES,RC5..
I don't need an implementation for them I just need to use them in c#
I'm new in this field and need help
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find the urls below for DSE,SDES,RC5:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19538/Encrypt-Decrypt-String-using-DES-in-C

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91628/Simplified-version-of-the-DES-Data-Encryption-Stan

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22518/Encryption-with-RC-Algorithm

Comment: I tried these links and find that rc5 code doesn't work> any another RC5 c# code??  please help

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace on [MSDN - cryptography tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yx4d854%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and here [MSDN - cryptography namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx). These should get you started with encrypting and decrypting strings, not sure if it covers all the algo's you are after.